# Run a Program when user Double Clicks USB Drive

Tags: windows, shell, autorun

I need to run a program/Flash File when a user double clicks the USB Drive.I could do this with autorun like this

```
    [autorun]
    icon=mypic.ico
    open=myapp.exe
```

But it seems newer versions of windows have blocked autorun.Im not sure about it.Is there any other way by which i can achieve this. Please advice.

Comment: No, there isn't. Autorun has been disabled by default, because installing malware off of removable devices is not what users prefer. If you want to initiate an action, have the user explicit do so.

Comment: @IInspectable okay... thanks